# Cannot set IME Keyboard entry method independently from Tab to Tab in new Chromium EDGE

Tags: tabs, microsoft-edge, ime

The new Chromium EDGE does not seem to support independent IME keyboard entry methods from Tab to Tab. In the previous version of MS EDGE, the keyboard entry method could be set independently from Tab to Tab ...   alphabet (for English, French, Spanish, etc entry) or various characters sets for Japanese (Kanji, hiragana, katakana).

In addition, the IME keyboard entry method could be independently changed per EDGE Tab with a simple keyboard Hot-Key action. Now, the same entry method hot-key action changes the entry methods for ALL tabs including Tabs open in 2nd or more EDGE window(s).

Is this an oversight on the part of the MS EDGE development team, or is there a setting somewhere that will allow me to use a different IME keyboard entry method from Tab to Tab?

This issue severely impacts my work flow as I do lots of research and translation between English to Japanese and Japanese to English.

Comment: There is no setting to achieve your desired behavior in the MS Edge (Chromium) browser. Does the suggestion I provided you in the answer to help you to get the answer for your question? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

At present, I did not get any setting to achieve your desired behavior in the MS Edge (Chromium) browser.

If you think that this feature should be available in the MS Edge (Chromium) browser then please try to provide the feedback to Microsoft by clicking the **Send Feedback** button in the MS Edge (Chromium) browser.

I understand that this behavior is impacting your work. If you think that the MS Edge legacy browser works as per your requirement then you can try to use the MS Edge legacy browser and MS Edge (Chromium) browser side by side. It may help you to avoid the issue temporarily.

Reference:

[Access Microsoft Edge Legacy after installing the new version of Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-sysupdate-access-old-edge)